# vite Internal server error Bindings not found

Tags: reactjs, vite

Everything was working fine, then all of sudden, out of nowhere, I started getting this error

`4:27:58 PM [vite] Internal server error: Bindings not found.   Plugin: vite:react-swc   File: /Users/admin/workspace/metrics/client/src/index.tsx       at Compiler.<anonymous> (/Users/admin/workspace/metrics/client/node_modules/@swc/core/index.js:225:19) ....`

My Project is using Vite and react - with the following deps:

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.7.10",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.1",
    "d3": "^7.8.5",
    "date-fns": "^2.30.0",
    "date-fns-tz": "^2.0.0",
    "date-format": "^4.0.14",
    "glamor": "^2.20.40",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "mobx": "^6.8.0",
    "mobx-react": "^7.6.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.9.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.10.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "reactflow": "^11.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.8.2",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@swc/cli": "0.1.62",
    "@swc/core": "1.3.66",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.191",
    "@types/node": "^16.18.13",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.28",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
    "@types/uuid": "^9.0.1",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react-swc": "3.3.2",
    "js-yaml": "3.13.1",
    "ts-deep-extract-types": "^1.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.3",
    "vite": "^4.2.0"
  }
}
```

I have already tried to `rm -rf node_modules`, `rm -rf package-lock.json` and reinstalled everything. Nothing works. I can no longer run my project. Anyone knows the fix for this?

Answer (score 3):

I came across the same error, couldn't find any working solution, so, basically
the only thing was to revert back to react-vite NON swc.

p.s. i read about people just reinstalling the packages / installing the swc/core and stuff. nothing i've tried worked :(

###### 1. changed the vite config file like this:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react' //removed swc

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [react()],
})
```

###### 2. edit the package.json from:

```
"@vitejs/plugin-react-swc": "^3.0.0",
```

to

```
"@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.0",
```

###### 3. delete the previous packages

- delete *package-lock.json*
- delete *node_modules*

##### 4. Install the needed packages

```
npm install
```

Comment: but I want to use swc... it has better performance

Comment: not as fast if you cant even start the dev server ahahah but on a serious note, if you have a solution please share it in an answer

Comment: I finally fixed it. I posted the solution as an answer

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution in this [github issue](https://github.com/vitejs/vite-plugin-react-swc/issues/74):

```
npm install --force --save-optional \
    @swc/core \
    @swc/core-darwin-arm64 \
    @swc/core-darwin-x64 \
    @swc/core-linux-arm-gnueabihf \
    @swc/core-linux-arm64-gnu \
    @swc/core-linux-arm64-musl \
    @swc/core-linux-x64-gnu \
    @swc/core-linux-x64-musl \
    @swc/core-win32-arm64-msvc \
    @swc/core-win32-ia32-msvc \
    @swc/core-win32-x64-msvc
```

The bug happens when npm generates the lockfile with an existing node_modules that contains platform-specific dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

try `npm i -D @swc/cli @swc/core`

Answer (score 0):

Try this. it will solve the issue.

`npm i -D @vitejs/plugin-react-swc`